# Save the order or a column

Tags: numbers

I have some words in column B. They are sorted by a personal criterion, nothing that Apple Numbers can consider:

[image]

At a certain point, I want to organize the information by another criterion. For instance, to make it simple, sort ascending:

[image]

Is there a way I can go back to the first picture?

(Here I simplify the case. Of course, I could cmd z, but that is not the point. I am looking for an easy way to save a specific order even after I close the file o even days later)

What I have tried: 
This is a simplified case. In real live I have several files with thousands of rows in each file. I cannot create a column and give them a number of reference manually. I tried to create a column and generate the order this way:

1- I put 1 in A1
2- Put A1+1 in A2
3- Copy paste the formula in the other columns. Or drag the yellow point, it's the same
4- Create another column and "paste results" (When I sort by the B column the formula column will change. That's why I need that extra step and create a column with only numbers)

This works, but it seems complicated and I need to do it many times. Is there any other way to **save the order** that is easier, simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create an Index column.  1, 2, 3 etc. (As pjctec mentions in comments.). Without some ordered list or index, there is no way for Numbers to know how to use a custom sort.

There is no need to use a formula to create the list of numbers.

1. In `A1` enter `1`
2. In `A2` enter `2`
3. In `A3` enter `3`
4. Select cells `A1 to A3`
5. Drag the yellow dot down.

Sorting will not change the numbers as they are static.  No need to use a formula.

Then you can always sort the index column later.  If needed, the column can be hidden or shown when needed.

Apple supplies a good resource for Numbers basics on their Website. [Numbers Help](https://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/4.2/). Recommended for new users and anyone who wants to get the most out of using Numbers.

[image: Sort and re-sort]

Comment: That is the solution that I already explained. The question is that I cannot manually write the index column. There are thousands of references. Please read where I explain "What I have tried"

Comment: See my edit.  No need for a formula such as `A1 + 1` to create the list.  But it is recommended to learn what you can about how spreadsheets applications such and Numbers or Excel use formulas, do sorting etc.  Cheers.